# Random averages over a Point process - Campbell's Theorem

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, moments

Let $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a non-homogeneus Poisson process with intensity function $t \mapsto \lambda(t)$. Let $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the corresponding  simple point process (arrival times), namely 
$$N_t = \sum_n \mathbf{1}_{\{0 < T_n \leq t \}}.$$
For a measurable subset $A \subseteq [0, \infty)$ denote by $N(A)$ the number of arrivals in $A$.

Campbell's theorem states that for a measurable function $f\colon [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\int_{[0, \infty)} \min\{|f(t)|, 1\} \lambda(t)dt <\infty  $$
the characteristic function of 
$$\Sigma :=  \sum_{i=1}^{N([0, \infty))} f(T_i) = \int_0^\infty f(t)dN(t)$$
is given by 
$$\varphi_{\Sigma}(r) = \mathbb{E}[e^{ir\Sigma}] = \exp\left\{\int_{[0, \infty)} (e^{irf(t)}-1)\lambda(t)dt\right\}$$
provided that the integral on the right-hand side converges for each $r$. 
Therefore, we can get all the moments of $\Sigma$.

There is also a paper by Privault "Moments of Poisson stochastic integrals with random integrands" [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4854.pdf) which gives all moments to a more general problem.

Assuming that the intensity function $\lambda$ is a PDF of a distribution supported on $[0, \infty)$, I would like to find moments (at least first two) of 
$$\frac{1}{1+N([0, \infty))} \Sigma?$$

I was not able to calculate it, the issue is that we have a product of two correlated random variables. I could not find it in the literature on the Poisson process, there was nothing on "random averages" over a point process. 
Maybe it is trivial, but I have no idea how to approach it. I would be grateful for any relevant references.

My attempt:
Let $f$ be a measurable function.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{1+ N([0, \infty))} \Sigma \right]
=& \sum_{m \geq 1} \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{1+ m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} f(T_k) \Big| N([0, \infty))=m)\right]\mathbb{P}(N([0, \infty))=m) \\=& \sum_{m \geq 1}  \frac{1}{1+m} \sum_{k=1}^m \mathbb{E}[f(T_k)]\mathbb{P}(N([0, \infty))=m) \\
=&  \sum_{m \geq 1}  \frac{1}{1+m} \mathbb{P}(N([0, \infty))=m) \sum_{k=1}^m \int_0^{\infty} f(t) p_k(t) dt, 
\end{align*}
where $p_k$ is the pdf of $k$-th point $T_k$.

Comment: Just derive it from the first principles like you did with Campbell's theorem (in which you forgot exponentiation on the RHS). Note that to get $N([0,+\infty))$ finite with probability $1$, you have to assume that $\int_0^\infty\lambda<+\infty$. Condition upon $N([0,+\infty))=k$ and get a series representation for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I simplified it. It looks almost like $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{1+N([0, \infty])}] \int_0^{\infty} f(t) \lambda(t)dt$. Do you agree, now? Or is there a way or further simplification?

Comment: Almost but not quite. The actual factor is $e^{-1}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac 1{k+1}\frac 1{(k-1)!}$ while your factor $E[\frac 1{1+N}]$ is  $e^{-1}\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac 1{k+1}\frac 1{k!}$. If we agree on that, then everything is correct.

Comment: I cannot work out, why it should be $\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$ instead of $\frac{1}{k!}$. Could you please give another hint, I had this idea with changing the indices, but then I decided that it was wrong. We have to exclude the case when $N=0$ because then there would be no arrivals.

Comment: It is just $\frac 1{k+1}P(N=k)E]\sum_{j=1}^k f(X_j)]=\frac 1{k+1}e^{-1}\frac 1{k!}k\int f\lambda$ where $E$ is taken with respect to the distribution with pdf $\lambda$.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that $\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{j=1}^k f(X_j)\right] = k \int f \lambda$ rather than $\sum_{j=1}^k \int f p_k(t)dt$.

Comment: It can be written either way but the first is much simpler.

Comment: it should have been $p_j(t)$ and it is a pdf of an Erlang-$j$ distribution. Ok, so it is sorted then, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Also, your $\lambda$ is not a number but a function, so the words "Erlang distribution" should be understood accordingly.

Comment: Yes, of course.